# Android Studio SQlite create for each day automatically an new table with current date as name

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

As the title says, I need to create automatically each day a new table with the current date as tablename. I found a solution to name the table as the current date, but I am not sure if my code creates the table automatically for each new day. The table for today was created successfully, but does my code work for this purpose after midnight?

Here is my code:

```
 public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context,DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTableDay = "CREATE TABLE " + getCurrentTableName()+"("
            + DAY_COL_1 + " TEXT UNIQUE ,"
            + DAY_COL_2 + " TEXT ,"
            + DAY_COL_3 + " TEXT "+
            ")";
    db.execSQL(createTableDay);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}


public boolean addData(String time,String town,String speed){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DAY_COL_1,value);
    contentValues.put(DAY_COL_2,value);
    contentValues.put(DAY_COL_3,value);
    long result = db.insert(getCurrentTableName(),null,contentValues);

    if(result == -1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}


private String getCurrentTableName() {
    long systemDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    currentTableName = currentDate.format(systemDate);
    currentTableName = "["+currentTableName+"]";
    return currentTableName;
}
```

Comment: Why not just having one table and storing the date of the day in a column in it? Something like a table per day is usually a very bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The table for today was created successfully, but does my code work for this purpose after midnight?

From the code shown then **No** as the **onCreate** method only runs once when the database is created. If the database exists then **onCreate** is not run and thus no other table will be created.

However, using seperate tables for will introduce unecessary complications (as has been alluded to in the demos below re crossing days) and also very likely unecessary inefficiencies.

- each table will require two additional schema entities each of which will take up some memory as SQLite keeps a copy of the schema in memory.
- a table requires a minimum of 4k (by default) per page, likewise for an index. So that's 8k per day.
- How would you use a previous days data? What if you need data from multiple days? (rhetorical). If the answer is only the last days data is used then a single table would suffice where the previous days data is deleted.

It is highly likely that a single table would suit.

The follwoing  is an example where a table per day (if accessed on that day) would be created. In this case no tables (other than system and android specific (android_metadata) tables) are created.

The tables are created when and as needed. In the example that is when they are accessed (adding or querying) :-

## DatabaseHelper.java :-

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DAY_COL_1 = "d1";
    public static final String DAY_COL_2 = "d2";
    public static final String DAY_COL_3 = "d3";

    String SQLITEMASTER_TABLENAME = "sqlite_master";
    String SQLITEMASTER_COLNAME = "name";
    String SQLITEMASTER_COLTYPE = "type";

    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");
    String currentTableName;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public boolean addData(String time, String town, String speed) {

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DAY_COL_1, time);
        contentValues.put(DAY_COL_2, town);
        contentValues.put(DAY_COL_3, speed);
        return db.insert(getTodaysTable(), null, contentValues) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor getAllData() {
        return db.query(
                getTodaysTable(),
                null,null,null,null,null,null
        );
    }

    private boolean doesTableExist(String tableName) {
        boolean rv = false;
        String whereclause = SQLITEMASTER_COLNAME + "=? AND " + SQLITEMASTER_COLTYPE + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{tableName,"table"};
        Cursor csr = db.query(
                SQLITEMASTER_TABLENAME,
                null,
                whereclause,
                whereargs,
                null,null,null
        );
        if (csr.getCount() > 0) rv = true;
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    private String getTodaysTable() {
        currentTableName = getCurrentTableName();
        if (!doesTableExist(currentTableName)) {
            db.execSQL(getCurrentTableCreateSQL());
        }
        return currentTableName;
    }

    private String getCurrentTableCreateSQL() {
        return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + getCurrentTableName() +
                "(" +
                DAY_COL_1 + " TEXT UNIQUE ," +
                DAY_COL_2 + " TEXT ," +
                DAY_COL_3 + " TEXT " +
                ")";
    }

    private String getCurrentTableName() {
        return currentTableName = "[" + currentDate.format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "]";
    }

    public void logEntitiesInDatabase() {
        Cursor csr = db.query(
                SQLITEMASTER_TABLENAME,
                null,null,null,
                null,null,null
        );
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(
                    "DBENTITYINFO",
                    "Name = " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(SQLITEMASTER_COLNAME)) +
                            " Type = " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(SQLITEMASTER_COLTYPE))
            );
        }
    }
}
```

- Note the **`logEntitiesInDatabase`** method is just for debugging/reporting purposes and is not intrinsic to the methodology.

## Demo 1

This demonsrates the automatic creation of the table when adding some rows.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        mDBHelper.logEntitiesInDatabase();
        mDBHelper.addData("10:20","Xington","50");
        mDBHelper.addData("10:21","Yington","55");
        mDBHelper.addData("10:30","Zington","40");
        mDBHelper.logEntitiesInDatabase();
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(mDBHelper.getAllData());
    }
}
```

This :-

1. Instantiates the database helper, which will create the database if it doesn't exist (run 1).
2. Lists (in the Log) all of the Database Entities (Tables, Indexes, Triggers, Views etc)

   1. For run 1 it will just list android_metadata (this table is created by the SDK's SQlite API behinds the scenes).
3. Add's three rows to the database.

   1. If a new date, then the table will be created and rows added to the new table.
   2. If row's were added crossing from one day to another then thos added for the new day would be added to a new table.
4. Again all the Database Entities are listed.
5. Retrieves all rows from the current table and dumps them to the log.

   1. Note that you if the data being added crosses a day then it will only retrieve data for the new day.

### Demo 1 - Run 1 result

```
2019-12-15 07:44:43.302 D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = android_metadata Type = table
2019-12-15 07:44:43.322 D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = android_metadata Type = table
2019-12-15 07:44:43.322 D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = 15-12-2019 Type = table
2019-12-15 07:44:43.322 D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = sqlite_autoindex_15-12-2019_1 Type = index
2019-12-15 07:44:43.325 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@9a330ae
2019-12-15 07:44:43.325 I/System.out: 0 {
2019-12-15 07:44:43.325 I/System.out:    d1=10:20
2019-12-15 07:44:43.325 I/System.out:    d2=Xington
2019-12-15 07:44:43.325 I/System.out:    d3=50
2019-12-15 07:44:43.325 I/System.out: }
2019-12-15 07:44:43.325 I/System.out: 1 {
2019-12-15 07:44:43.325 I/System.out:    d1=10:21
2019-12-15 07:44:43.326 I/System.out:    d2=Yington
2019-12-15 07:44:43.326 I/System.out:    d3=55
2019-12-15 07:44:43.326 I/System.out: }
2019-12-15 07:44:43.326 I/System.out: 2 {
2019-12-15 07:44:43.326 I/System.out:    d1=10:30
2019-12-15 07:44:43.326 I/System.out:    d2=Zington
2019-12-15 07:44:43.326 I/System.out:    d3=40
2019-12-15 07:44:43.326 I/System.out: }
2019-12-15 07:44:43.326 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

## Demo 1 - Run 2 result

```
2019-12-15 08:04:35.155 D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = android_metadata Type = table
2019-12-15 08:04:35.155 D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = 15-12-2019 Type = table
2019-12-15 08:04:35.155 D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = sqlite_autoindex_15-12-2019_1 Type = index
2019-12-15 08:04:35.158 E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting d1=10:20 d2=Xington d3=50
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: 15-12-2019.d1 (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:879)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:790)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:88)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1599)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1468)
        at a.so59337775createtableperday.DatabaseHelper.addData(DatabaseHelper.java:46)
        at a.so59337775createtableperday.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2019-12-15 08:04:35.163 E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting d1=10:21 d2=Yington d3=55
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: 15-12-2019.d1 (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:879)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:790)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:88)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1599)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1468)
        at a.so59337775createtableperday.DatabaseHelper.addData(DatabaseHelper.java:46)
        at a.so59337775createtableperday.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2019-12-15 08:04:35.169 E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting d1=10:30 d2=Zington d3=40
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: 15-12-2019.d1 (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:879)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:790)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:88)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1599)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1468)
        at a.so59337775createtableperday.DatabaseHelper.addData(DatabaseHelper.java:46)
        at a.so59337775createtableperday.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2019-12-15 08:04:35.179 D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = android_metadata Type = table
2019-12-15 08:04:35.179 D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = 15-12-2019 Type = table
2019-12-15 08:04:35.179 D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = sqlite_autoindex_15-12-2019_1 Type = index
2019-12-15 08:04:35.185 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41b5ae5
2019-12-15 08:04:35.186 I/System.out: 0 {
2019-12-15 08:04:35.186 I/System.out:    d1=10:20
2019-12-15 08:04:35.186 I/System.out:    d2=Xington
2019-12-15 08:04:35.186 I/System.out:    d3=50
2019-12-15 08:04:35.186 I/System.out: }
2019-12-15 08:04:35.186 I/System.out: 1 {
2019-12-15 08:04:35.186 I/System.out:    d1=10:21
2019-12-15 08:04:35.186 I/System.out:    d2=Yington
2019-12-15 08:04:35.186 I/System.out:    d3=55
2019-12-15 08:04:35.186 I/System.out: }
2019-12-15 08:04:35.186 I/System.out: 2 {
2019-12-15 08:04:35.186 I/System.out:    d1=10:30
2019-12-15 08:04:35.186 I/System.out:    d2=Zington
2019-12-15 08:04:35.187 I/System.out:    d3=40
2019-12-15 08:04:35.187 I/System.out: }
2019-12-15 08:04:35.187 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

- i.e. no difference other than rejection of the Add due to UNIQUE constraint conflicts.

## Demo 2

This demonstrates that even just querying the database using the **getAllData** method creates the database as the table name is retrieved via the **getTodaysTable()**.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        mDBHelper.logEntitiesInDatabase();
        /*
        mDBHelper.addData("10:20","Xington","50");
        mDBHelper.addData("10:21","Yington","55");
        mDBHelper.addData("10:30","Zington","40");
         */
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(mDBHelper.getAllData());
        mDBHelper.logEntitiesInDatabase();
    }
}
```

### Demo 2 - Run 1 result

```
2019-12-15 08:20:28.361 D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = android_metadata Type = table
2019-12-15 08:20:28.368 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@9a330ae
2019-12-15 08:20:28.369 I/System.out: <<<<<
2019-12-15 08:20:28.370 D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = android_metadata Type = table
2019-12-15 08:20:28.370 D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = 15-12-2019 Type = table
2019-12-15 08:20:28.370 D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = sqlite_autoindex_15-12-2019_1 Type = index
```

### Demo 2 - Run 2 result

```
2019-12-15 08:26:28.032D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = android_metadata Type = table
2019-12-15 08:26:28.032D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = 15-12-2019 Type = table
2019-12-15 08:26:28.032D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = sqlite_autoindex_15-12-2019_1 Type = index
2019-12-15 08:26:28.034I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@9a330ae
2019-12-15 08:26:28.035I/System.out: <<<<<
2019-12-15 08:26:28.036D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = android_metadata Type = table
2019-12-15 08:26:28.036D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = 15-12-2019 Type = table
2019-12-15 08:26:28.036D/DBENTITYINFO: Name = sqlite_autoindex_15-12-2019_1 Type = index
```